# ModuleNotFoundError when running Qiskit RNG

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

I'm trying to generate random numbers using IBMQ backends with the following code:

```
pip install qiskit_rng
from qiskit_rng import Generator

IBMQ.load_account()
rng_provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')
backend = rng_provider.backends.ibmq_manila

generator = Generator(backend=backend)
output = generator.sample(num_raw_bits=20001).block_until_ready()
qiskit_raw = output.raw_bits
print(qiskit_raw)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
  Input In [3] in <cell line: 2>
    from qiskit_rng import Generator
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit_rng/__init__.py:52 in <module>
    from .generator import Generator
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit_rng/generator.py:35 in <module>
    from qiskit.providers.basebackend import BaseBackend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.providers.basebackend'
```

How can I fix this error? My current version of terra is 0.21.2. Also, is there a way to recreate this process? It is my understanding that IBM uses the GHZ (Greenberger–Horne–Zeilinger) states and then measures them with random X- and Y-measurements. I would appreciate if someone can confirm that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `qiskit-rng` is [0.2.2](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-rng/0.2.2/) from January 2021. **It is unmaintained** since then and their [github repo is archived](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit_rng). Based on [their `requirements.txt` file](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit_rng/blob/master/requirements.txt):

```
qiskit-ibmq-provider>=0.10
qiskit-terra>=0.16.2
```

You can get exactly these with:

```
pip install "qiskit-terra==0.16.2"
pip install "qiskit-ibmq-provider~=0.10"
```

It should work after that.

Comment: It does! Thank you! Is there currently a better way implemented by IBM to get some rng?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If you have a strong use case for it, I would call the community on slack to consider writing and supporting one.